# How long should I expect to wait for payout on p2pool

Tags: p2pool, pool-payout-methods

Basically, I have 20 GH/s running on p2pool I've had no pay out for about 4 days which seems a long time.

The time to share is also 110 hours and stays at 110 hours. It never drops and so am getting 0 shares in 5 days.

Basically my question is this normal? will it suddenly kick in or is there something wrong with my setup.

Comment: I don't mine myself at p2pool, but you should get shares, and you should get regular payouts. Are you sure everything is working alright? No shares means (afaik) that something is wrong.

Comment: Thats sort of why I asked, everything seems fine, no errors etc. in p2pool logs bfgminer is send stuff across and activity is logged in p2pool as it all should, but the time to share stays sat very high.

Comment: I don't mine at p2pool, acually I'm mining at eligius. Bitcoin payments enter the payout queue when you reach 0.04BTC, at my speed (300GH/s) I get paid every 4days aprox. So to answer your question you need to know what amount you must reach to enter the payout queue and then calculate the time it will take for your first coins to arrive.

Comment: You're being "credited" for your work at your p2pool. However, actual payments won't be made until/unless your p2pool actually finds a block - it may be several days for that event. Once it does happen, though, all payments so far deferred will be effected.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just needed to be patient, is sorted now.